# Sliding to open on ios does not do the needed job

Tags: ios

Sliding from the lock screen and/or pressing a notification from the notifications page... do both pass from applicationDidFinishLunchingWithOptions when the app is totally closed?

My concern is because, when the app is closed and not in background, whenever I press on the app from the notification, my app opens and goes where it has to go... but whenever I press slide to open, the app opens but it does not go to the page it should go.

Comment: Based on the type of your notification it goes to either:
`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo`
OR
`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification`

Answer (score 1):

The docs say that if the action button on the notification is pressed, it calls application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and passes in the notification payload. Later it says if the app is running in the foreground, it delivers the notification via application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:. This implies to me that when the app is backgrounded or not running, then application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called. Otherwise, application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: is called.

application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: will only be called if your app is not launched already. While it is true that the options will include info on notifications if that is what ended up launching the app, what you want is to handle your local notification logic here:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```